# How to make the inline ckeditor toolbar fixed at the top and not float

Tags: position, ckeditor, toolbar, floating

I am using inline CKEditor in my page. I want to make it fixed on the top of the contenteditable div. Currently it is floating whenever i scroll the page. How to make the toolbar position fixed at the top?

Answer (score 4):

Use the combination of inline editor and the [Shared Space](http://ckeditor.com/addon/sharedspace) plugin. Check the [Inline Editor with Shared Toolbar and Bottom Bar](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/samples/sharedspace.html) demo on the CKEditor SDK page for an example. Note that you can view and download the source code of each SDK example - just scroll down to "Get Sample Source Code" and grab what you need.

```
<div id="toolbarLocation></div>
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true"></div>

<script>

    CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', { 
        sharedSpaces: { 
            top: 'toolbarLocation' 
        } 
    } );

</script>
```