# Positioning toolbar to page top

Tags: ckeditor

How to make the editor toolbar located just above? I use inline editing, and the toolbar is transferred down if to scroll a site before the end of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Using [sharedspace](http://ckeditor.com/addon/sharedspace) can help you.
You can find a similar issue, and the solution, here:
[How to make the inline ckeditor toolbar fixed at the top and not float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22028087/how-to-make-the-inline-ckeditor-toolbar-fixed-at-the-top-and-not-float)

The implementation of the plugin would look like this:

```
<div id="toolbarLocation></div>
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true"></div>

<script>

     CKEDITOR.disableAutoInline = true;
     CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', { 
         sharedSpaces: { 
             top: 'toolbarLocation' 
         } 
     } );

</script>
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Just added the code of the other answer, thanks for the reply.